# Why can I no longer drag image files from Lightroom Classic straight to an open Photoshop Document?

Tags: adobe-lightroom

I recently moved from a Mac to a PC at work. Formerly, on my Mac I was able to drag an image straight from Lightroom to an open InDesign or Photoshop file. I am finding now, on the pc that I am unable to do this. Is there some fix for this or will I have to alter my workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can confirm that clicking and dragging from the Libary module doesn't work in Windows, however you would be better to ask Adobe why it doesn't work.

Until Adobe fixes it, you can right click an image and choose *Edit in > Edit in Photoshop*. And to get an image into another application, you can right click it, and choose *Show in Explorer*, and when Explorer opens, the file will be highlighted, and from there you can click and drag it into another application.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have posted on Adobe with no response. The "Show in Explorer" seems to be the best option for me. So far I am not a fan of Windows. I will prob just take me a little while to adjust.

Comment: @jseymour - to be fair, this isn't a Windows problem. You can easily drag and drop an image from Bridge for example.  So, Adobe needs to fix this.